# "zip -r xxx.zip xxx" never stop

Tags: node.js, shell, zip, node-modules

(I want to zip a folder to xxx.zip )
I have a node package which contains node_modules file tree like this

```
├── build.sh
├── logs
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── run
├── src
├── test
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
└── velocity.log
```

when i run

```
zip -r mydirname.zip mydir
```

the command never to stop and always print like below log

```
....
    zip warning: name not matched: mydirname/node_modules/egg-bin/node_modules/espower-typescript/node_modules/espower-source/node_modules/espower/node_modules/escope/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext
    zip warning: name not matched: mydirname/node_modules/egg-bin/node_modules/espower-typescript/node_modules/espower-source/node_modules/espower/node_modules/escope/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es6-symbol/node_modules/d
    zip warning: name not matched: mydirname/node_modules/egg-bin/node_modules/espower-typescript/node_modules/espower-source/node_modules/espower/node_modules/escope/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es6-symbol/node_modules/ext
    zip warning: name not matched: mydirname/node_modules/egg-bin/node_modules/espower-typescript/node_modules/espower-source/node_modules/espower/node_modules/escope/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/next-tick
    zip warning: name not matched: mydirname/node_modules/egg-bin/node_modules/espower-typescript/node_modules/espower-source/node_modules/espower/node_modules/escope/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator
    zip warning: name not matched: mydirname/node_modules/egg-bin/node_modules/espower-typescript/node_modules/espower-source/node_modules/espower/node_modules/escope/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext/node_modules/es6-symbol
...
```

### reproduction way

```
$ mkdir -p mydir
$ cd mydir
$ npm i egg-bin
$ cd ..
$ zip -r mydirname.zip mydir
```

hwo to fix this to get a zip file?

Answer (score 0):

this is because symbolic link
use -y to store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file.

```
zip -r -y mydirname.zip mydir
```